# how to check if workbook is closing in deactivate event

Tags: vba, excel

**SOLVED**

Is there any way to check if workbook is closing when the code is in workbook_deactivate procedure? so i can inform a different message to users depending on whether they are just leaving to another workbook or they are closing the file. like following

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

if thisworkbook.closing then
   msgbox "message1"
else
   msgbox "message2"
end if

End Sub
```

i've searched on the net but no solution at all.
so any help would be appreciated

**SOLUTION**

i've thought of a trick. i'm putting the value 1 in Z1000(if it is available) in before_close event and in deactivate, i'm checking if Z1000's value. that's it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Range("Z1000").Value = 1 'wherever is avaliable
    Me.Saved = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    If Range("Z1000").Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "quitting"
    Else
        MsgBox "deactivating"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a `Workbook_Close` event, but unfortunately there isnt a Workbook_BeforeClose` event in VBA or a `Workbook.Closing` property. If I am not mistaken, the `BeforeClose` event is exposed in C#, so there may be a way to get at the event through VBA.

Comment: @BrandonBarney are you sure? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-beforeclose-event-excel ... Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @GibralterTop You are correct. There is an event. I could've sworn it wasnt there when I last needed it. My bad!

Comment: @BrandonBarney It could very well be newer, which mean it may not work depending on the version of Excel OP is using. The author of the article doesn't specify release or compatibility.

Comment: @GibralterTop Just checked and it is in mine as well, I just must've missed it the first time. So, it was likely just me being an idiot :p .

Comment: well, there is a before_close event in excel, but i cannot use it. coz i want to catch the close event in deactivate so when i close the file only one event will be fired. otherwise both before_close and deactivate will fire. i only want to deactivate to fire, but in that i want to catch if the file is closing

Answer (score 1):

You can detect that using the `BeforeClose` Event

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  ' set Cancel to true to prevent it from closing
End Sub
```

Comment: @brandon - Good catch. fixed it.

Comment: well, there is a before_close event in excel, but i cannot use it. coz i want to catch the close event in deactivate so when i close the file only one event will be fired. otherwise both before_close and deactivate will fire. i only want to deactivate to fire, but in that i want to catch if the file is closing

Comment: That's not possible.